# Ghostscript: What are the differences between Linux and Windows variants?

Tags: windows, linux, ghostscript

I am working with Ghostscript for Linux. What are the differences?

Comment: Differences with what?  GS on Linux is the same as GS on other platforms.  Do you want to know (for example) if there are any dialectic differences between GS and the Adobe PS interpreter?  You really need to elaborate on your question and make it clearer.

Comment: One of its legs is both the same.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know difference from Linux to *MS Windows* (you didn't specify)... from the top of my head:

- On Windows you have two executables, `gswin32c.exe` and `gswin32.exe` instead of `gs` only. The first one is to run Ghostscript on the commandline ("DOS box"), the second one will open two GUI windows: one to render the output, another one which is console-like and shows GS stdout/stderr or takes your command input if you run GS in interactive mode.
- On Windows you'll see a few less *"devices"* if you type `"gswin32c.exe -h"` compared to `"gs -h"`. Most noteably you'll not have any of the `x11*` devices (like x11, x11alpha, x11cmyk, x11mono etc). You'll also not have the `cups` device, nor the OpenPrinting Raster/Vector devices (`oprp` and `opvp`).
- On Windows you'll have two additional devices called *mswindll* and *mswinpr2*.
- It is recommended to use forward slashes for path/directory separation also on Windows (otherwise you'd possibly need to use a double backslash `\\` to escape the single one).
- Printing to a real printer is handled differently on Windows. Use `-sOutputFile=` to print to your default printer. Use `-sOutputFile="%printer%My Nice Ricoh Printer"` to print to the named printer.